# Como calcular a diferença entre duas datas ignorando os finais de semana em Java sem utilizar loop

Tags: java, data, jodatime

Estive a procura de uma solução para este problema mas não encontrei um algoritmo satisfatório, então resolvi criar o algoritmo. Espero que sirva para alguém.

```
public int betweenDaysIgnoreWeekends(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    //Um numero que representa o dia da semana para a data final, exemplo segunda=1, terça=2, quarta=3...
    int dayOfWeekEndDateNumber = Integer.valueOf(endDate.dayOfWeek()
            .getAsString());
    //Um numero que representa o dia da semana para a data inicial, exemplo segunda=1, terça=2, quarta=3...
    int dayOfWeekStartDateNumber = Integer.valueOf(startDate.dayOfWeek()
            .getAsString());
    //Se a data final for sabado ou domingo, finja ser sexta-feira
    if (dayOfWeekEndDateNumber == 6 || dayOfWeekEndDateNumber == 7) {
        int DaysToAdd = 8 - dayOfWeekEndDateNumber;
        endDate = endDate.plusDays(DaysToAdd);
        dayOfWeekEndDateNumber = Integer.valueOf(endDate.dayOfWeek()
                .getAsString());
    }

    //Se a data inicial for sabado ou domingo, finja ser segunda-feira
    if (dayOfWeekStartDateNumber == 6 || dayOfWeekStartDateNumber == 7) {
        int DaysToAdd = 8 - dayOfWeekStartDateNumber;
        startDate = startDate.plusDays(DaysToAdd);
        dayOfWeekStartDateNumber = Integer.valueOf(startDate.dayOfWeek()
                .getAsString());
    }

    //Quantos dias se passaram contando os fins de semana
    int days = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays();
    //Quantas semanas se passaram exatamente
    int weeks = days / 7;
    //O excesso de dias que sobrou, exemplo: 1 semana e 3 dias o excess=3 e weeks=1
    int excess = days % 7;

    //Se a data inicial for igual a data final, passou 0 dia
    if (startDate.equals(endDate)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        //O excesso de dias passou pelo fim de semana, então deve-se retirar 2 dias
        //da quantidade final de dias
        if (excess + dayOfWeekStartDateNumber >= 6) {
            //Quantidade de semanas * 5 dias uteis + o excesso de dias - o final de semana que o excesso atravessou
            return weeks * 5 + excess - 2;
        }
        //Quantidade de semanas * 5 dias uteis + o excesso de dias
        return weeks * 5 + excess;
    }
}
```

Comment: Legal seu algoritmo, mas existe um pequeno problema na forma como você está transmitindo seu conhecimento, você deve fazer uma pergunta e responder ela mesma, como se fossem duas pessoas diferentes, uma perguntando e outra respondendo. Dá uma olhada [nesse link aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1845/3117)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como disse @Math, o correto seria perguntar e colocar sua resposta. Depois marcar sua resposta como aceita, assim a pergunta não fica aparecendo nas questões sem respostas do SO.

De qualquer forma vou adicionar um algoritmo que uso para esse fim como resposta, não precisa marcar ele como aceita, pode responder com a sua e marcar ela.

```
static long days(Date start, Date end){
    //Ignore argument check

    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(start);
    int w1 = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -w1);

    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.setTime(end);
    int w2 = c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    c2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -w2);

    //end Saturday to start Saturday 
    long days = (c2.getTimeInMillis()-c1.getTimeInMillis())/(1000*60*60*24);
    long daysWithoutSunday = days-(days*2/7);

    return daysWithoutSunday-w1+w2;
}
```

Este algoritmo é baseado na resposta do SO em Inglês deste link https://stackoverflow.com/a/4600534/747802