# Diferença entre duas datas, ignorando final de semana - dias úteis apenas

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Estava procurando algo parecido, porém infelizmente não encontrei nada.

Encontrei essa solução que me ajudou muito mas é em Java.
[Como calcular a diferença entre duas datas ignorando os finais de semana em Java sem utilizar loop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30774/como-calcular-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-duas-datas-ignorando-os-finais-de-semana-em-java)

Gostaria em C#.

**Como retornar os dias entre 2 datas ignorando os finais de semana. Apenas os dias úteis?**

Comment: [tem uns exemplos aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94496/retirar-s%C3%A1bados-e-domingos-do-c%C3%A1lculo/94568#94568)

Comment: Como já possui excelentes respostas, irei deixar apenas [este pacote](https://github.com/kappy/DateTimeExtensions/wiki/Working-days) que trabalha com feriados, inclusive.

Comment: @Randrade você usa? Viu algo como ela pega os feriados? Faz para o futuro? Até quando? Lida com feriados regionais?

Comment: @bigown Não uso mais, pois não tenho necessidade, mas já usei e tenho sistemas usando até hoje (com adaptações). Os feriados você adicionar [nesta classe](https://github.com/kappy/DateTimeExtensions/blob/e79c3d1eb85dde60953d43db1055518aec5ad511/DateTimeExtensions/WorkingDays/CultureStrategies/PT_BRHolidayStrategy.cs). Faz sim para o futuro, com os mesmos feriados definidos. Até quando você quiser, mas sempre serão nas mesmas datas. Lida sim com feriados regionais, mas você precisa adicioná-los na classe. Se ficou mais alguma dúvida, chame no chat que explico melhor.

Comment: @bigown Pode ver [um exemplo aqui](http://datetimeextensions.azurewebsites.net/pt-BR/Calendar/Index/2016)

Comment: A pergunta não trata de feriados, então é sim uma duplicata de uma pergunta anterior.

Answer (score 5):

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculates number of business days, taking into account:
///  - weekends (Saturdays and Sundays)
///  - bank holidays in the middle of the week
/// </summary>
/// <param name="firstDay">First day in the time interval</param>
/// <param name="lastDay">Last day in the time interval</param>
/// <param name="bankHolidays">List of bank holidays excluding weekends</param>
/// <returns>Number of business days during the 'span'</returns>
public static int BusinessDaysUntil(this DateTime firstDay, DateTime lastDay, params DateTime[] bankHolidays)
{
    firstDay = firstDay.Date;
    lastDay = lastDay.Date;
    if (firstDay > lastDay)
        throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect last day " + lastDay);

    TimeSpan span = lastDay - firstDay;
    int businessDays = span.Days + 1;
    int fullWeekCount = businessDays / 7;
    // find out if there are weekends during the time exceedng the full weeks
    if (businessDays > fullWeekCount*7)
    {
        // we are here to find out if there is a 1-day or 2-days weekend
        // in the time interval remaining after subtracting the complete weeks
        int firstDayOfWeek = (int) firstDay.DayOfWeek;
        int lastDayOfWeek = (int) lastDay.DayOfWeek;
        if (lastDayOfWeek < firstDayOfWeek)
            lastDayOfWeek += 7;
        if (firstDayOfWeek <= 6)
        {
            if (lastDayOfWeek >= 7)// Both Saturday and Sunday are in the remaining time interval
                businessDays -= 2;
            else if (lastDayOfWeek >= 6)// Only Saturday is in the remaining time interval
                businessDays -= 1;
        }
        else if (firstDayOfWeek <= 7 && lastDayOfWeek >= 7)// Only Sunday is in the remaining time interval
            businessDays -= 1;
    }

    // subtract the weekends during the full weeks in the interval
    businessDays -= fullWeekCount + fullWeekCount;

    // subtract the number of bank holidays during the time interval
    foreach (DateTime bankHoliday in bankHolidays)
    {
        DateTime bh = bankHoliday.Date;
        if (firstDay <= bh && bh <= lastDay)
            --businessDays;
    }

    return businessDays;
}
```

[Chupei dessa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1619375/221800). Ela tem a vantagem que pode passar feriados. lembrando que feriado é algo que deve ser obtido de outra fonte e pode variar de acordo com o município/estado (não necessariamente o seu) e em que ano está.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/L0x34g). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zp4juU). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/BusinessDay.cs).

Answer (score 4):

Acabei fazendo este código que funciona muito bem:

```
   public static int GetDifDias(DateTime initialDate, DateTime finalDate)
        {
            var days = 0;
            var daysCount = 0;
            days = initialDate.Subtract(finalDate).Days;

            if (days < 0)
                days = days * -1;

            for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
            {
                initialDate = initialDate.AddDays(1);
                
                if (initialDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday &&
                    initialDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                    daysCount++;
            }
            return daysCount;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Mais uma maneira juntando a solução enxuta do @emerson-js com a solução do @Maniero que inclui feriados:

```
public static int CountDiasUteis(DateTime d1, DateTime d2, params DateTime[] bankHolidays)
{
    List<DateTime> datas = new List<DateTime>();

    for (DateTime i = d1.Date; i <= d2.Date; i = i.AddDays(1))
    {
        datas.Add(i);
    }

    return datas.Count(d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday &&
                            d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday &&
                            !bankHolidays.Contains(d));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Amigos, apenas mais uma forma de se fazer:

```
public static int CountDiasUteis(DateTime d1, DateTime d2) {

   int fator = (d1 > d2 ? -1: 1);

   List<DateTime> datas = new List<DateTime>();

   for (DateTime i = d1.Date; (fator==-1 ? i >= d2.Date : i <= d2.Date); i = i.AddDays(fator)) {
      datas.Add(i);
   }

   return datas.Count(d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && 
                           d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday) * fator;            

}
```

Comment: achei ótima seu código mas ele não retorna dias negativos ex: 06/06 para 16/06 deveria retornar -10

Comment: Ocorre que normalmente quando falamos de passagem de tempo imaginamos sempre números positivos. De qualquer forma adaptei o código e agora é possível retornar valores negativos. Veja só como ficou.